# How to create simple forum for ASP.NET MVC web site?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, forum

I want to provide forum for users of my web page.

This is my idea:

---

[image]

---

**My questions:** How can I do this kind of forum using ASP.NET MVC ? Is there any tutorial ? Particulary hard seems to be the editor (WYSIWYG)... Is there any existing solution/library/framework for MVC that will allow me to do this ? Is it custimisable enough for me to get this design (including colors) ?

---

So this is the list of features I would like to provide:

1. form of one comment:

   2. on the top left profile picture
   3. on top right user name followed by some other info
   4. below profile picture button for upvoting the post and upvotes count
   5. below user name the content
2. content of the post is from some text and may contain pictures and hyperlinks
3. at the and of forum there is an editor for new post. User can add links and pictures to post and they will be displyed in the post (WYSIWYG editor)

Thank you